# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { script.js:5 request.onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

When running the code below, I’m getting an error:

```
var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','data.json');
request.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if((request.readyState===4)&&(request.status==200)){
        var customers=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(customers);
    }
}
request.send();
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { script.js:5 request.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: easy: your data.json is malformed

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you, problem was in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your data.json is malformed

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in JSON.parse. Add a console.log in the previous line

```
    console.log(request.responseText);
    var customers=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(customers);
```

also controls that the responseText doesn't have a utf-8 BOM.